# Auto-mount cryfs on startup

Tags: startup, automounting

cryfs requires a password/passphrase entry for mounting a filesystem.

I want to automatically mount a FS at startup 
(like calling a script from inside of rc.local to do the job).

(the encrypted file system to be mounted already exists)

Can i give the password as a hash?

I do not want to save it plain text in my startup script.

Any idea, how to overcome this issue?

thx in advance!

Linux system...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necro bump here, but since I started working on this project, this answer always pops up first.  I was able to solve this issue, without a security risk (as far as I know, I'm no expert) using the following method. This is of course dependent on using 'gnome keyring', and the main keyring sharing your user login password.

- install: `libsecret-tools` and `expect`
- in terminal, run

  ```
  secret-tool store --label="cryfs" cryfs cryfs
  ```
- enter `cryfs` password
- write a first script (in my case `cryfs.sh`)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/expect -f

  set password [lindex $argv 0];

  spawn cryfs ~/Dropbox/cryfs-vault ~/cryfs-source
  expect "Password: "
  send "$password\r"
  expect eof
  ```
- write second script (`autocryfs.sh`)

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  password=$(/usr/bin/secret-tool lookup cryfs cryfs)
  /path/to/script/cryfs.sh $password
  ```
- make both scripts executable

  ```
  chmod +x /path/to/script/scriptname.sh
  ```

Finally mark the script to run on boot (in my case - Linux Mint - added to system settings > startup applications > add > custom command > Name: Cryfs, command `/path/to/script/autocryfs.sh startup delay: 5`

Answer (score 0):

If this were possible, then anyone could mount that system after reading the hash from your startup file, without having to know the password.  So leaving the hash in plain text would essentially become just as insecure as leaving the password in plain text.  For this reason, no, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Storing your hashed password in a non-encrypted file is a potential hazard if you can get access to your fs using this hashed password.

Any encryption does not make any sense if you do not have authentication procedure which could be just a text password, your fingerprint, your face or eye picture and etc.

Another question if you want it to be automatically mounted once you passed this authentication procedure. I think this is possible and you don't need to store any hashed passwords for that.

eCryptfs could be auto-mounted if a user password matches with selected eCryptfs password. More information how to make it done could be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs#Auto-mounting). Once you entered gnome password your home directory will be automatically mounted.